# C++ Dll string function crash

Tags: c++, string, sockets, dll, crash

I have the following problem.
I use the following function to receive a string from a buffer until a newline occurs.

```
string get_all_buf(int sock) {
    int n = 1, total = 0, found = 0;
    char c;
    char temp[1024*1024]; 
    string antw = "";

    while (!found) {
        n = recv(sock, &temp[total], sizeof(temp) - total - 1, 0);
        if (n == -1) {

            break;
        }
        total += n;
        temp[total] = '\0';
        found = (strchr(temp, '\n') != 0);

        if (found == 0){
        found = (strchr(temp, '\r\n') != 0);
        }
    }
    antw = temp;

    size_t foundIndex = antw.find("\r\n");
    if (foundIndex != antw.npos)
    antw.erase ( antw.find ("\r\n"), 2 );

    foundIndex = antw.find("\n");
    if (foundIndex != antw.npos)
    antw.erase ( antw.find ("\n"), 2 );

    return answ;
}
```

So use it like this:

```
string an = get_all_buf(sClient);
```

If I create an exe file everything works perfectly.
But if I create a dll and run it using rundll32 the application closes at "`string an = get_all_buf(sClient);`" without any error message...

I tried to fix this for hours now, and I am currently a bit desperate...

P.S. sorry for obvious errors or bad coding style, I just started learning C++.

Comment: Why would you run it using rundll32.exe? Besides you don't have any environment then, don't you? Build a C++-project in VS and link to your DLL.

Comment: Can you also include the *proc* that you're running from rundll32's command line that is eventually calling this? It may be important. Aside from that, see simon's answer below as your guess is as good as mine what rundll32 uses for a default stack size (likely exactly 1MB, so you should be dyna-allocing that temp buffer).

Answer (score 3):

```
char temp[1024*1024];
```

declares a 1Mb structure on the stack.  This may be too large and overflow available stack memory.  You could instead give it static scope

```
static char temp[1024*1024];
```

or allocate it dynamically

```
char* temp = (char*)malloc(1024*1024);
// function body
free(temp);
```

Alternatively, assuming the mention of run32.dll means you're working on Windows, you could investigate keeping it on the stack by using the [/STACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx) linker option.  This probably isn't the best approach - you've already found it causes problems when you change build settings or try to target other platforms.

Comment: WOW! It worked!
char temp[1024*1024];  worked perfectly
Thank you so much !!! :D
such a simple solution and i had trouble for hours ^^

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating `temp` variable on the stack, I'd create it dynamically (on the heap), but not using raw `malloc` and `free` as showed in a previous answer, but using modern C++ and **`std::vector`**:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> temp(1024*1024);
```

This is exception safe, and you don't have to pay attention to release the allocated memory: `std::vector`'s destructor will do that *automatically* (also in case of exceptions thrown).

Instead of `sizeof(temp)`, in your code you can use `temp.size()` (which will return the count of elements in the vector, and since this is a vector of `char`s, it will return just the total vector size in `char`s i.e. in bytes).

You can still use `operator[]` for `std::vector`, as you do for raw C arrays.

Note also that if you are building a **DLL** and the above function is exposed at the DLL interface, since this function has a **C++ interface with a STL class (`std::string`) at the boundary**, you must pay attention that both your DLL and your clients are built with *dynamic linking* to the *same CRT*, and with the *same compiler* and the *same compiler settings* (e.g. you can't mix a DLL built with VS2008/VC9 with a .EXE built with VS2010/VC10, or a release-build DLL with a debug-build EXE built with the same compiler).